# React-router auto redirect after Redux action

Tags: javascript, redux, react-router

I would like to ask, what would be the best solution to make automatic redirect, after an async actoin creator was called in redux?

I read React router passes down to its components history object, but since I am doing and async action with redux, I dont have any access to the object.

I found there is a possibility to make an own History object, where I can define my history and then link it directly to the script where I call the redux actionCreator.

But is this solution the best practise or is there any better/cleaner solution?

Comment: Please enlighten me, just looking for the best solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of doing it is just passing in the history object that the component receives into the async redux action.

For example, something like this:

```
const action = (arg1,arg2,history)=>async(dispatch,getState)=>{
  history.push('/')
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I read about this solution too, but is it better than the ones I mentioned? Im just trying to learn it in the best form as possible. So I am curious about all pros and cons

Comment: They are both possible to be done. This way requires less configuration you have to do yourself. Which you like more is really up to your preference, though.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your input, I will wait a bit longer if somebody adds something else and if not I will accept your answer